# What is the correct way to load pdb symbols to show the functions by their name instead of their addresses in x64dbg?

Tags: x64dbg, symbols

I am trying to reverse a portion of a game, that game loads a DLL file called "ddraw.dll".
Most of the DLL file functions don't appear by their names but appear by their addresses

for example:

```
; The function address '67415A6A' but no name
ddraw.67415A6A
```

So, I have known that can download the PDB symbols file for the "ddraw.dll" file to make all their functions appear by their names instead of their addresses.
And that is what I did, I have downloaded the symbols for "ddraw.dll" using the command `symdownload/downloadsym` and download it to the path "x64dbg\x32\symbols", then I reopen the debugger again to see what happened but nothing happened, all functions still appear by their addresses.
I tried to use `symload/loadsym` command to load "ddraw.dll" symbols but it always gives me "invalid module" although, I have written the command correctly `symload path\game.exe, path\symbols\ddraw.pdb,0 or 1`.

**How do I solve that problem?**